# Android programming, draw a rectangle with specific coordinates

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. I am trying to draw a rectangle as in the image below. I have no idea how to do it with Rect(int left, int top, int right, int bottom). Can someone help me with this thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://android.okhelp.cz/draw-rect-android-basic-example/
http://alvinalexander.com/android/how-to-draw-rectangle-in-android-view-ondraw-canvas

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
Paint p = new Paint();
// smooths
p.setAntiAlias(true);
p.setColor(Color.RED);
p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
p.setStrokeWidth(4.5f);
canvas.drawRect(10, 10, 30, 30, p);
```